# Is it possible to render multiple viewports in different pixels of the same frame (combined, not separated)?

Tags: opengl

What I want to implement are as follows:

(I can only post one picture :(, so I put them in one and tagged them in a letter)

I want to combine multiple viewports in one frame but **not** like [N]

If the viewports are like these: [A] and [B], I want to combine them like [C]:

What is the best practice to achieve this?

[ref picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AOU7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use several techniques to combine two renderings into one image like the one in image C.

I assume that you want to generate an image where A and B are rendered as interleaved stripes into one frame buffer.

You could use a **stencil mask**. Therefore you have to render image A to the framebuffer first. Draw the pattern where image B should be drawn into the same framebuffer. Make sure to only render the stencil values but not any color values (glColorMaski). After that you can render image B with activated stencil buffer test.

An alternative solution would be to check the **fragement location** in a fragment shader and **reject pixels** which are not part of the stripe pattern. Note that this solution is only a viable option if you implement a fragment shader by yourself and in cases where the pattern to draw can be expressed as a formula. Free from masks are a domain where the stencil buffer is in advantage.

Comment: In your stencil mask technique you could also render the pattern first and for example render A only when stencil==0 and render B when stencil==1. This would save some unnecessary fragment shader calls for A.

Comment: Note that the stencil test for discarding fragments done after the fragment shader runs in the default OpenGL rendering pipeline. So if you want to save some fragment shader calls you have to use **early fragment testing** (https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Early_Fragment_Test) to make it worth the effort.

Comment: I'm pretty sure early fragment testing is done by default on all hardware. The cost to not do it would be just too high (thinking of scenes with high depth complexity).